# sql join query issues

Tags: sql, join

Im making a friends list which JOINs 2 tables, the FRIENDS table, and the PLAYERS table.

friends table

```
 player   target     status
 -----------------------------
 john     eric       invited
 roger    moore      friends
 stan     winston    friends
```

players table

```
 name      pic     
 -------------------
 john     lol.jpg
 stan     skinhead.gif
```

Now when on a players page, I need to loop through the `friends` table and find out how many friends they have. So for this i'd have to check BOTH the `player` field, and the `target` field that = $name

Then to get the pic id have to JOIN that with the `players` table.

This is my query so far, which doesnt work obviously (bit of psuedo):

```
SELECT p.pic, p.name FROM friends f INNER JOIN players p ON (player OR target)=p.name WHERE (f.player='" .$name. "' OR f.target='" .$name. "') AND status='friends'
```

$name is the name of the players profile you are on.

Can anyone tell me how to tweak this to make it work?

Comment: Could you explain specifically what part of your query doesn't work and what error/incorrect results you get?

Comment: This will be closer:

SELECT p.pic, p.name FROM friends f INNER JOIN players p ON friends.player=p.name WHERE (f.player='" .$name. "' OR f.target='" .$name. "') AND status='friends'

Comment: Its to do with the JOIN, ive done it in psuedo atm. It could either be the f.player OR the f.target I need to JOIN with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a union to get it all in one query.

```
SELECT * FROM friends JOIN players ON (target = name AND status = friends)
WHERE player = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM friends JOIN players ON (player = name AND status = friends)
WHERE target = ?
```

Comment: Of course, you should probably be using some kind of unique ID to identify people, rather than just their name.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT p.pic, p.name FROM friends f INNER JOIN players p ON f.name=p.name WHERE (f.player='" .$name. "' OR f.target='" .$name. "') AND status='friends`'

friends = f.player
in your query ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.pic, 
       p.name 
FROM friends f 
   INNER JOIN players p ON p.name IN (f.player, f.target)
WHERE (f.player='" .$name. "' OR f.target='" .$name. "') 
AND status='friends'
```

which is a shorthand for

```
SELECT p.pic, 
       p.name 
FROM friends f 
   INNER JOIN players p ON p.name = f.player OR p.name = f.target
WHERE (f.player='" .$name. "' OR f.target='" .$name. "') 
AND status='friends'
```